# Grouped Product

Tags: shipping

Make a small shop for vacuumbags. So i want to use table rate shipping for my grouped product with option # of items vs. destination. Because: Products inside of grouped product have different quantity(100, 500 or 1000), size and weight. For example: you choose an grouped product and pick 2-3 different sizes of this bags and i want that Magento see that i choose not 2-3 but 200 or 300. Option with weight cannot work because i have no possibility to weigh them. So i want to give to each product wich are inside of grouped product theit package quantity and table rate should take this value. Hope its possible somehow : /
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the qty into weight, then you can do it just by weight.